# Tab content structure Ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm new at php, I want to do a three tab structure with button that goes back and forward if some conditions are accepted:

- First tab just go forward if i click on the button
- Second tab go forward if the privacy check button is checked
- Third tab, fields to compile like name,surname,email.... and send data based on the request
  This structure is based on a disservice report that the user meets.
  I'm working with this basic example with two tab who use a javascript code and the php template based on Ajax communication of the data.

Tha javascript code:

```
!function(){const l=document.querySelector(".container-segnalazione");
async function e(){const r=l.querySelector(".steppers-content");
if(r){  
    var e=r.querySelector("#category");
if(e){
    const o=r.querySelector("#service");o&&(e.addEventListener("change",async e=>{r=o,t=r.firstElementChild,r.innerHTML="",r.append(t),r.disabled=!0;
    var t=e.target.value;if(t){var r=await async function(e){
        try{
            return await(await fetch(window.wpRestApi+"wp/v2/servizi"+(e?"?categorie_servizio="+e:""))).json()}catch(e){console.error(e)}}(t);
    if(Array.isArray(r)){
        for(servizio of r){
            var a=servizio?.title?.rendered,n=document.createElement("option");n.value=a,n.innerHTML=a,o.add(n)}
            1<o.childElementCount&&(o.disabled=!1)}}}),r.addEventListener("submit",async()=>{var e,t=r.querySelector(".errorFeedback"),t=(t&&t.remove(),await async function(){
                try{
                    var e=l.querySelector('[name="name"]').value,
                    t=l.querySelector('[name="surname"]').value,
                    r=l.querySelector('[name="email"]').value,
                    a=l.querySelector("#category").value,
                    n=l.querySelector("#service").value,
                    o=l.querySelector("#description").value,
                    c=l.querySelector("#privacy").checked,
                    i={title:"ticket_"+(new Date).toISOString(),nome:e,cognome:t,email:r,categoria_servizio:a,servizio:n,dettagli:o,privacyChecked:c},
                    s=/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                    return 0<(Object.values(i)?.filter(e=>!e))?.length||!s.test(r)?!1:(await fetch(data_segnalazione.url,{method:"POST",credentials:"same-origin",headers:{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Cache-Control":"no-cache"},body:new URLSearchParams({action:"save_richiesta_assistenza",...i})})).ok}catch(e){console.error(e)}}());
                    t?(document.getElementById("first-step").classList.add("d-none"),
                    document.getElementById("second-step").classList.add("d-none"),
                    document.getElementById("email-recap").innerText=l.querySelector('[name="email"]').value,
                    document.getElementById("third-step").classList.remove("d-none"),
                    (t=document.querySelector(".menu-wrapper"))&&t.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"})):((t=document.createElement("p")).classList.add("form-feedback","just-validate-error-label","ms-0"),t.innerText="something went wrong, try again",(e=document.createElement("div")).classList.add("errorFeedback"),e.appendChild(t),t=e,(e=r.querySelector(".privacy-wrapper"))&&r.insertBefore(t,e))}))}}}l&&e()}();
```

And this is the wp_enqueue function in the php file:

```
function dci_enqueue_dci_segn_script()  {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dci-segnalazione', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assistenza.js', array(), null, true );
    $variables = array(
        'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    );
    wp_localize_script('dci-segnalazione', "data_segnalazione", $variables);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dci_enqueue_dci_segn_script' );
```

Can someone help me to do these steps or hints to complete this work.

I try to delete the content and do a simply page with a button to go forward but the button doesn't work, I think depends on how the javascript file is structured. The php file use form for the input data, i can't append the php file because has a very large number of lines.

Comment: The php part looks ok.  Is the file ‘assistenza.js’ found by the browser?

Comment: Anyway: your Javascript is minified. Better write code yourself then to start of with someone elses minified Javascript. I don’t want to spend time to uglify your code.

Comment: Yes, i know, this is just an example where to start but i don't know how to start, my goal for now i s to do a tab structure with a first tab and a button to go forward to the next tab and after  a privacy check tab where if you check the box you can push the button and go to the third tab.

Comment: Start by learning the basics of Javascript, I would say. Sounds like relatively beginner task. But you have to start learning to write Javascript code before doing beginner stuff.